# Creating a Docker container that runs forever using bash

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to create a Pod with a container in it for testing purposes that runs forever using the K8s API. I have the following yaml spec for the Pod which would run a container and exit straight away:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-example
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ubuntu
    image: ubuntu:trusty
    command: ["echo"]
    args: ["Hello World"]
```

I can't find any documentation around the `command:` tag but ideally I'd like to put a while loop in there somewhere printing out numbers forever.

Comment: What should the container do?  The `echo` command you show there will print out `Hello world` to the pod logs and then exit immediately.  (You usually wouldn't run a plain `ubuntu` image, and "run forever" without doing anything isn't generally an interesting container.)

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, it's for testing purposes, just need something that won't exit right away

Comment: i think maybe `command: ["while :; do echo 'Hello'; sleep 1; done"]` would do it

Comment: have you tried it? where did you have a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep printing `Hello` every few seconds you can use:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox2
  labels:
    app: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "while :; do echo 'Hello'; sleep 5 ; done"]
```

You can see the output using `kubectl logs <pod-name>`

Other option to keep a container running without printing anything is to use `sleep` command on its own, for example:

```
command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec", "sleep 10000"]
```